# How can I fix errors about imports in this code?

Tags: android, import

I have this code to compress pictures , but I have three errors about imports , I show which imports are errors in the code

1. The import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media collides with another import statement
2. The import android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media collides with another import statement
3. The import android.view.View.OnClickListener collides with another import statement

How can I fix them ???

```
package com.example.resizingimages;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media;
//first error is here : import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
//second error is here : import android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
//third error is here : import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class GetImageActivity extends Activity
  implements MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient, DialogInterface
{
  private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1800;
  private static final int GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED = 1500;
  private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
  static String filePath;
  private TextView Name;
  private TextView Size;
  MediaScannerConnection conn;
  File file;
  private String filename;
  private int height;
  Uri imageUri;
  private ImageView img;
  private Uri outputFileUri;
  Uri outputFileUri1;
  String path1;
  private String path2;
  private Bitmap picture;
  private File root;
  File sdImageMainDirectory;
  private Uri selectedImageUri;
  private int width;

  private void cameraaa(String paramString, Uri paramUri)
  {
    while (true)
    {
      try
      {
        InputStream localInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(paramUri);
        BitmapFactory.Options localOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        localOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
        localOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
        localOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        localOptions.inTempStorage = arrayOfByte;
        this.picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(localInputStream, null, localOptions);
        switch (new ExifInterface(paramString).getAttributeInt("Orientation", 1))
        {
        case 4:
        case 5:
        default:
          this.img.setImageBitmap(this.picture);
          String str = sizee(paramUri);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Size of Image " + str, 0).show();
          System.out.println("Image Path : " + paramString);
          return;
        case 6:
          rotateImage(this.picture, 90);
          continue;
        case 3:
        }
      }
      catch (Exception localException)
      {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error " + localException.getMessage(), 0).show();
        return;
      }
      rotateImage(this.picture, 180);
    }
  }

  public static String getDataColumn(Context paramContext, Uri paramUri, String paramString, String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    Cursor localCursor = null;
    String[] arrayOfString = { "_data" };
    try
    {
      localCursor = paramContext.getContentResolver().query(paramUri, arrayOfString, paramString, paramArrayOfString, null);
      if ((localCursor != null) && (localCursor.moveToFirst()))
      {
        String str = localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data"));
        return str;
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      if (localCursor != null)
        localCursor.close();
    }
    if (localCursor != null)
      localCursor.close();
    return null;
  }

  public static String getPathl(Context paramContext, Uri paramUri)
  {
    int i;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
      i = 1;
    while ((i != 0) && (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(paramContext, paramUri)))
      if (isExternalStorageDocument(paramUri))
      {
        String[] arrayOfString3 = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(paramUri).split(":");
        if (!"primary".equalsIgnoreCase(arrayOfString3[0]))
          break label271;
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + arrayOfString3[1];
        i = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        if (isDownloadsDocument(paramUri))
        {
          String str2 = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(paramUri);
          return getDataColumn(paramContext, ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(str2).longValue()), null, null);
        }
        if (!isMediaDocument(paramUri))
          break label271;
        String[] arrayOfString1 = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(paramUri).split(":");
        String str1 = arrayOfString1[0];
        Uri localUri;
        if ("image".equals(str1))
          localUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        while (true)
        {
          String[] arrayOfString2 = new String[1];
          arrayOfString2[0] = arrayOfString1[1];
          return getDataColumn(paramContext, localUri, "_id=?", arrayOfString2);
          if ("video".equals(str1))
          {
            localUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
          }
          else
          {
            boolean bool = "audio".equals(str1);
            localUri = null;
            if (bool)
              localUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
          }
        }
      }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(paramUri.getScheme()))
      return getDataColumn(paramContext, paramUri, null, null);
    if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(paramUri.getScheme()))
      return paramUri.getPath();
    label271: return filePath;
  }

  public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri paramUri)
  {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(paramUri.getAuthority());
  }

  public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri paramUri)
  {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(paramUri.getAuthority());
  }

  public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri paramUri)
  {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(paramUri.getAuthority());
  }

  private void openAddPhoto()
  {
    String[] arrayOfString = { "Camera", "Gallery" };
    AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    localBuilder.setTitle(getResources().getString(2130968578));
    localBuilder.setItems(arrayOfString, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt)
      {
        if (paramAnonymousInt == 0)
        {
          ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
          localContentValues.put("title", "new-photo-name.jpg");
          localContentValues.put("description", "Image capture by camera");
          GetImageActivity.this.imageUri = GetImageActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, localContentValues);
          Intent localIntent1 = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
          localIntent1.putExtra("output", GetImageActivity.this.imageUri);
          GetImageActivity.this.startActivityForResult(localIntent1, 1800);
        }
        if (paramAnonymousInt == 1)
        {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
          {
            Intent localIntent2 = new Intent();
            localIntent2.setType("image/*");
            localIntent2.setAction("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
            GetImageActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(localIntent2, "Select Picture"), 1);
          }
        }
        else
          return;
        Intent localIntent3 = new Intent("android.intent.action.PICK", MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        GetImageActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(localIntent3, "Select Picture"), 1500);
      }
    });
    localBuilder.setNeutralButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt)
      {
        paramAnonymousDialogInterface.dismiss();
      }
    });
    localBuilder.show();
  }

  private void startScan()
  {
    if (this.conn != null)
      this.conn.disconnect();
    this.conn = new MediaScannerConnection(this, this);
    this.conn.connect();
  }

  public void cancel()
  {
  }

  public void dismiss()
  {
  }

  public String getPath(Uri paramUri)
  {
    Cursor localCursor = managedQuery(paramUri, new String[] { "_data" }, null, null, null);
    String str = null;
    if (localCursor != null)
    {
      int i = localCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
      localCursor.moveToFirst();
      str = localCursor.getString(i);
    }
    return str;
  }

  public String name(String paramString)
  {
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; ; j++)
    {
      if (j >= paramString.length())
      {
        this.filename = filePath.substring(i + 1, paramString.length());
        return this.filename;
      }
      if (paramString.charAt(j) == '/')
        i = j;
    }
  }

  public void onActivityResult(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, Intent paramIntent)
  {
    if (paramInt2 == -1)
    {
      if (paramInt1 == 1)
        while (true)
        {
          try
          {
            this.selectedImageUri = paramIntent.getData();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA " + filePath, 0).show();
            filePath = getPath(this.selectedImageUri);
            InputStream localInputStream2 = getContentResolver().openInputStream(this.selectedImageUri);
            BitmapFactory.Options localOptions2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            localOptions2.inSampleSize = 2;
            localOptions2.inPurgeable = true;
            byte[] arrayOfByte2 = new byte[1024];
            localOptions2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            localOptions2.inTempStorage = arrayOfByte2;
            this.picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(localInputStream2, null, localOptions2);
            switch (new ExifInterface(filePath).getAttributeInt("Orientation", 1))
            {
            case 4:
            case 5:
            default:
              this.img.setImageBitmap(this.picture);
              String str4 = sizee(this.selectedImageUri);
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Size of Image " + str4, 0).show();
              return;
            case 6:
              rotateImage(this.picture, 90);
              continue;
            case 3:
            }
          }
          catch (Exception localException3)
          {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error " + localException3.getMessage(), 0).show();
            return;
          }
          rotateImage(this.picture, 180);
        }
      if (paramInt1 == 1500)
        while (true)
        {
          try
          {
            this.selectedImageUri = paramIntent.getData();
            getPathl(getApplicationContext(), this.selectedImageUri);
            getContentResolver();
            filePath = getPathl(getApplicationContext(), this.selectedImageUri);
            InputStream localInputStream1 = getContentResolver().openInputStream(this.selectedImageUri);
            BitmapFactory.Options localOptions1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            localOptions1.inSampleSize = 2;
            localOptions1.inPurgeable = true;
            byte[] arrayOfByte1 = new byte[1024];
            localOptions1.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            localOptions1.inTempStorage = arrayOfByte1;
            this.picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(localInputStream1, null, localOptions1);
            switch (new ExifInterface(filePath).getAttributeInt("Orientation", 1))
            {
            case 4:
            case 5:
            default:
              this.img.setImageBitmap(this.picture);
              String str3 = sizee(this.selectedImageUri);
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Size of Image " + str3, 0).show();
              return;
            case 6:
            case 3:
            }
          }
          catch (Exception localException2)
          {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error " + localException2.getMessage(), 0).show();
            return;
          }
          rotateImage(this.picture, 90);
          continue;
          rotateImage(this.picture, 180);
        }
      if (paramInt1 == 1800)
      {
        filePath = null;
        this.selectedImageUri = this.imageUri;
        if (this.selectedImageUri != null)
          while (true)
          {
            String str1;
            try
            {
              str1 = this.selectedImageUri.getPath();
              String str2 = getPath(this.selectedImageUri);
              if (str2 != null)
              {
                filePath = str2;
                if (filePath == null)
                  break;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " path" + filePath, 1).show();
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetImageActivity.class);
                cameraaa(filePath, this.selectedImageUri);
                return;
              }
            }
            catch (Exception localException1)
            {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error", 1).show();
              Log.e(localException1.getClass().getName(), localException1.getMessage(), localException1);
              return;
            }
            if (str1 != null)
            {
              filePath = str1;
            }
            else
            {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path", 1).show();
              Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    requestWindowFeature(1);
    getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
    setContentView(2130903040);
    Display localDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    this.width = localDisplay.getWidth();
    this.height = localDisplay.getHeight();
    final Button localButton = (Button)findViewById(2131296257);
    final Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(2131296260);
    final TextView localTextView = (TextView)findViewById(2131296259);
    localButton.setVisibility(4);
    localSpinner.setVisibility(4);
    localTextView.setVisibility(4);
    if (this.height <= 480)
    {
      localSpinner.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -2, 0, 20 + (this.height - this.height / 3)));
      localTextView.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(this.width, 60, 0, -20 + (this.height - this.height / 3)));
      localTextView.setText("Image Quality");
      localTextView.setText("Image Quality");
      this.img = ((ImageView)findViewById(2131296258));
      this.img.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
      this.height=-160;
      this.height=-160;
      this.width=(int) (0.8D * this.width);
      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams1 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams((int)(0.8D * this.width), (int)(0.5D * this.height), (int)(this.width - 0.9D * this.width), (int)(this.height - 0.9D * this.height));
      this.img.setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams1);
      ImageView localImageView = this.img;
      View.OnClickListener local1 = new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
          GetImageActivity.this.img.setImageDrawable(null);
          GetImageActivity.this.img.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
          localButton.setVisibility(0);
          localSpinner.setVisibility(0);
          localTextView.setVisibility(0);
          GetImageActivity.this.openAddPhoto();
        }
      };
      localImageView.setOnClickListener(local1);
      if (this.height > 480)
        break label505;
      localButton.setBackgroundResource(2130837507);
      this.height=-160;
    }
    for (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams2 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50, -25 + this.width / 2, -51 + this.height); ; localLayoutParams2 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(170, 170, -85 + this.width / 2, -170 + this.height))
    {
      localButton.setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams2);
      View.OnClickListener local2 = new View.OnClickListener()
      {

        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {

        }
      };
      localButton.setOnClickListener(local2);
      return;
      localSpinner.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -2, 0, 30 + (this.height - this.height / 3)));
      localTextView.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(this.width, 60, 0, -10 + (this.height - this.height / 3)));
      break;
      label505: localButton.setBackgroundResource(2130837506);
      this.height=-160;
    }
  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu)
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(2131230720, paramMenu);
    return true;
  }

  public void onMediaScannerConnected()
  {
    try
    {
      this.conn.scanFile(filePath, "image/*");
      return;
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException localIllegalStateException)
    {
    }
  }

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem paramMenuItem)
  {
    if (paramMenuItem.getItemId() == 2131296262)
      shareagain();
    while (true)
    {
      return true;
      if (paramMenuItem.getItemId() == 2131296263)
        try
        {
          startActivity(new Intent(this, readddme.class));
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error " + localException.getMessage(), 0).show();
        }
      else if (paramMenuItem.getItemId() == 2131296264)
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public void onScanCompleted(String paramString, Uri paramUri)
  {
    this.conn.disconnect();
  }

  public void rotateImage(Bitmap paramBitmap, int paramInt)
  {
    Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();
    localMatrix.setRotate(paramInt);
    this.picture = Bitmap.createBitmap(paramBitmap, 0, 0, paramBitmap.getWidth(), paramBitmap.getHeight(), localMatrix, true);
  }

  public void share()
  {
    Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
    localIntent.setType("text/plain");
    localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "#RABIDO");
    localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "#RABIDO");
    localIntent.setType("image/*");
    localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", this.selectedImageUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Share Image"));
  }

  public void shareagain()
  {
    Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
    localIntent.setType("text/plain");
    localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "Check out 'RABIDO' - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=decrease.image.uploader");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Share via"));
  }

  public String sizee(Uri paramUri)
  {
    String localObject;
    try
    {
      InputStream localInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(paramUri);
      byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
      int i = 0;
      float f;
      while (true)
      {
        if (localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte) == -1)
        {
          f = i / 1000;
          if (f >= 1000.0F)
            break;
          localObject = " " + i / 1000 + " KB";
          break label164;
        }
        i += arrayOfByte.length;
      }
      String str = " " + f / 1000.0F + " MB";
      localObject = str;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error 5 " + localException.getMessage(), 0).show();
      return "";
    }
    label164: return localObject;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the problematic imports, then press Ctrl + Shift + O, then crucially select the imports you want

Comment: Don't import them. If you are using classes with the same name from different packages, you can't. Use the full name in your code.

Comment: @CRUSADER when I remove them another errors appear ???

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem or do you need further help? If it did solve your problem, please check the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

1&2: these are actually both party of the same error. Import one of them and use the qualified name (i.e. android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media) for the other one so java knows which one you're referring to when you're just typing Media.

3: Same problem and solution, you have a view.onclicklistener and dialoginterface.onclicklistener. Import one or neither of them and use the full name.